# Proving $(I+T)^k$ has positive entries for large k

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning

This is mentioned in these [slides](http://www.math.harvard.edu/library/sternberg/slides/1180912pf.pdf).

A non-negative square matrix $T$ is called **primitive** if there is a $k$
such that all the entries of $T^
k$
are positive.

It is called irreducible
if for any$ i, j$ there is a $k = k(i, j)$ such that$ (T^
k
)_{ij} > 0.$

We have to show that if T is irreducible then I + T is primitive.

In the slides the author just does the binomial expansion since $I$ and $T$ commute and then says for large enough $k$ the entries are positive. I do not understand why? Can somebody explain this. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you expand out $(I+T)^n$ you get terms involving $T^k$ for every $k$ from $0$ to $n$.  If $n$ is large enough, this includes all the $k(i,j)$ from the definition of irreducible.  Since all terms are non-negative, if one is positive the sum is positive.